# Access denied with mmc.exe

Tags: mmc

I have a strange error that came up in front of me. I am getting an mmc.exe error (MMC is the Microsoft Management Console). When I open services.msc it gives me this error and it says

> Your administrator has blocked this service for security purpose".
> Source: "C:\Windows\System32\mmc.exe"  "C:\Windows\System32\services.exe"

What is the correct solution and how to fix this error?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This fixed it for me:

Use regedit.exe to navigate to this registry key: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System`

You have to set the value of "EnableLUA" to "0" (zero). A reboot is necessary.

Source/credits:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/1adf0029-1f06-4738-975a-4fd69b652168/uac-preventing-mmc-application-from-runnning

I hope it will help you too!